# Is there a way to programmatically create folders?

Tags: directory, xpages, ssjs

Is there a way to programmatically create folders?  There was a way to do it in lotus script - that method also was not documented in designer help.  I want to get a document collection and then put the whole collection into a folder.  I can see in the documentation that this will create the folder - I want to add columns to the folder.  I suppose at worst I can open the folder after it has been created from the "put" command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewEntryCollection.PutAllInFolder` method https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_PUTALLINFOLDER_METHOD_VEC_JAVA.html

The folder will be created from the view/folder flagged as "Default for new views/folders" property. To change its design, you can use `createColumn` method https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATECOLUMN_METHOD_VIEW_JAVA.html

Comment: Thanks so much - you actually touched on the problem we were having - there was no default view set and thus the creation of the folder failed.  Argh, rookie mistake that I shouldn't be making.

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon.  The code works if I try to put into the folder from a notesViewEntryCollection.  If I try to put it in via NotesDocumentCollection I get this error:
[TypeError] Error calling method 'PutAllInFolder(string, boolean)' on an object of type 'lotus.domino.local.DocumentCollection [Static Java Interface Wrapper, lotus.domino.local.DocumentCollection: lotus.domino.DocumentCollection]'

`code`
if (docColl.getCount() > 0 ){
           
 docColl.PutAllInFolder("Spicy3", true)
`code`

Comment: Argh, my bad.   At some point after proving the concept ".putInFolder" became ".PutInFolder"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the design by adding columns, it will need to run with a ID that has at least Designer access to the database. ODA has a design API that can be used to create design elements via DXL. I've used it to create views, but folders should work the same.

If you don't need to modify the design, you can create a Shared Private on First Use folder by running as the user and calling `getView()`. I don't think that needs designer access, but it's worth double-checking.

Note: the ODA methods haven't been tested from SSJS. If it works, you're lucky, but the focus is Java.